# What can we say about two spaces quotiented by the same group action?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

If $ X / U(1) \cong Y / U(1)$, what can I say about $X$ and $Y$ ? Will they also be isomorphic ? Here, $X$,$Y$ are two topological spaces and I chose $U(1)$ the circle action but it could be anything else.

Comment: If one of the actions isn't free then it's very easy to find a counterexample ($X=S^1$ with action by rotation, $Y=\{\ast\}$ with trivial action).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = S^2 \times S^1$ and $Y = S^3$, which are not homeomorphic to each other. Each of these has a free action by the circle group $U(1) = S^1$ whose quotient is homeomorphic to $S^2$.

To define the action on $X = S^2 \times S^1$, let $S^1$ act trivially on the $S^2$ factor and let it act by left multiplication on the $S^1$ factor.

To define the action on $Y = S^3$, use the Hopf action, which can be described by expressing $S^3$ as the group of unit quaternions $w + ix + jy + kz$, expressing $S^1$ as the group of unit complex numbers $s + it$, and letting $S^1$ act on $S^3$ by left quaternion multiplication.

There are many more such examples of $S^1$ acting freely on nonhomeomorphic 3-manifolds with homeomorphic quotient surfaces. Look up "Seifert fiber spaces".